# alternate for navigator.onLine in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having an issue with the navigator.onLine property.

it always returns true even the network is disconnected

**In html**

```
<p>{{online$ | async}}</p>
```

**In Ts**

```
import { Observable, fromEvent, merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class MyComponent {
  online$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.online$ = merge(
      of(navigator.onLine),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(true)),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(mapTo(false))
    );
  }
}
```

please suggest an alternate way for detecting internet connection

Comment: The `navigator.online` property is not reliable. In general, detecting network connectivity (or the lack of it) is a very difficult problem.

Comment: is there any other way to detect network connectivity ? @Pointy

Comment: Well think about it: connectivity varies literally from moment to moment. If you detect you are connected, you may be disconnected in a millisecond. A slow connection is hard to distinguish from the lack of any connection. Perhaps you could describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to show the user a toast whenever the internet connection is down like You're not connected to internet , please check your connection @Pointy

Comment: Why don't you just send a GET request to a dummy service on your side at regular intervals. If it times out after let's say 5 seconds you can set a flag to signal that the connection to the server is lost. As soon as your GET requests receive responses you can reset the flag.

Comment: what do you mean by dummy service , is I have to ping the server with get request? is that a reliable way to that . @Markus

Comment: @Renold Yes, that's what I mean. Just a simple service that is telling the caller, that the server is reachable and that is called by an asynchronous interval function. Just an idea if no one provides a better solution.